How to Provide attachment from JIRA to Jenkins
we have a JIRA-Jenkins pipeline where Attachment should be provided from Jira to  Jenkins job .
So,  Once required Transition of the workflow is clicked, the attachment will be provided from JIRA to the corresponding Jenkins job , which will be triggered and do its work, where aforementioned attachment will be used.
I am aware that there is concept of  custom_fields which are mapped to corresponding parameters defined in Jenkins job, with help of Groovy script. Here, issue is there is NO custom_field for attachment  as such in Jira form  , which can be used to map it to our 'file parameter' in Jenkins job in "This project is parameterized" option.
The ask here is what should be used in Groovy script for assigning this attachment  to file_parameter in Jenkins job?
I got to know there is some JIRA API which can be used to achieve this. As in, once transition is triggered , corresponding JIRA API will be assigned to a variable , which in turn will be mapped to this "FILE Parameter" in Jenkins job.
But need to have more insight about this specific JIRA API.
Please help.

You can use this Jira API documentation:

Java API: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/java-apis/
REST API: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/

E.g. to get the attachment by direct link, you can use https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/9.16.0/#api/2/attachment-getAttachment

To integrate Jira and Jenkins, specifically for passing an attachment from a Jira issue to a Jenkins job, you need to leverage Jira's REST API to fetch the attachment and then use it in your Jenkins pipeline.
First, you'll need to use the Jira REST API to get the attachment details. The endpoint for fetching attachments from a Jira issue is: 
GET /rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments
you may look for this demo and i hope it helps you
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import hudson.util.Secret
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

// Jenkins parameter name
def jenkinsFileParameterName = 'fileParam'

// Get credentials from Jenkins
def jiraApiToken = ''
def jiraUserEmail = ''
def jiraBaseUrl = 'https://your-jira-instance.atlassian.net'

// Use Jenkins Credentials Plugin to get Jira credentials
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'jira-api-token-id', variable: 'JIRA_API_TOKEN'), 
                 usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'jira-credentials-id', usernameVariable: 'JIRA_USER_EMAIL', passwordVariable: 'DUMMY_PASSWORD')]) {
    jiraApiToken = JIRA_API_TOKEN
    jiraUserEmail = JIRA_USER_EMAIL
}

// Jira issue key
def jiraIssueKey = 'PROJECT-123'

//you may make this variable value is dynamically fetched from jira plugin
// please look for it  


// Get the attachment details from Jira
def attachmentDetails = getJiraAttachments(jiraBaseUrl, jiraIssueKey, jiraUserEmail, jiraApiToken)
if (attachmentDetails.isEmpty()) {
    error "No attachments found for issue ${jiraIssueKey}"
}

// Download the first attachment
def attachmentUrl = attachmentDetails[0].content
def attachmentFilename = attachmentDetails[0].filename
def filePath = downloadFile(attachmentUrl, attachmentFilename, jiraUserEmail, jiraApiToken)

// Set the file parameter for Jenkins job
def fileParameter = new File(filePath)
if (!fileParameter.exists()) {
    error "Failed to download the attachment"
}
build.buildVariables.put(jenkinsFileParameterName, fileParameter.absolutePath)

// Functions
def getJiraAttachments(jiraBaseUrl, issueKey, userEmail, apiToken) {
    def url = "${jiraBaseUrl}/rest/api/3/issue/${issueKey}?fields=attachment"
    def connection = new URL(url).openConnection()
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "${userEmail}:${apiToken}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")

    if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
        def response = connection.inputStream.text
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
        return json.fields.attachment
    } else {
        error "Failed to fetch attachments from Jira: ${connection.responseMessage}"
    }
}

def downloadFile(fileUrl, filename, userEmail, apiToken) {
    def connection = new URL(fileUrl).openConnection()
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "${userEmail}:${apiToken}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString())

    def filePath = "/tmp/${filename}"
    Files.copy(connection.inputStream, Paths.get(filePath), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
    return filePath
}



